# How to effectively learn/understand OOP in C#?

Tags: c#, oop

in short, I've been going to C# classes for the last 6 months. We covered all fundamentals of the language - vars, arrays, methods, loops, text processing, working with strings etc. with lots of exercises... but as a whole the material was improving my algorithmic thinking (I don't have any programming background) and the things were going really well.

Since the middle of February however we started OOP and hard times arrived. It's a nightmare for me to implement the OOP principles, though I know them in theory.

What I do to help myself:

- read my C# class book
- read online resources
- read other people's code
- trying to write my own code fails

Can you give me suggestion please, as I don't want to give up!?

Comment: OO is an abstract concept that is more or less supported by langauges. Whilst I don't think you should give up there is not an objectively right answer to your question. This question covers much the same ground http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500475/learning-oop-well

Comment: This is not a programming question. So, it doesn't fit here. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: In short, keep trying.

Comment: @Soner "However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK." And I wanted other people to explain to me How to effectively learn/understand OOP in C#? What's the problem?

Comment: Although the question is closed, I advice to start programming (which you say fails), and if you encounter problems, ask that specific question (what failed, including code), you probably will get to the point answers and help you get further in the world of OOP.

Answer (score 3):

You have to start simple, even if the solution does not ask for a real OOP principe.

Also it is a good idea to read a book about design patterns, or more important: create your own (simple) apps with using them. Design patterns are very useful and heavily use OOP principles.

Comment: Our lectures mentioned Design Patterns, but said it's too early for beginners to use design patterns.

Comment: I still suggest in that case to just try programming, and when it fails, start with simpler examples. Use something with inheritance, then use aggregation, use several classes which look alike, try to move methods in base classes.

Answer (score 1):

try reading and understanding the following articles:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/tusharkantagarwal/objectorientedcsharp11162005070743AM/objectorientedcsharp.aspx